Azure FunctionsでPOSTされた画像を読み込みたいが、上手く行きません
以下のプログラムでPOSTされた画像を読もうとしているのですが、request.fileが取得できません。何が悪いのでしょうか？
JavaScriptのプログラミングモデルはv4です。
クライアントプログラム
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <button id="uploadButton">Upload</button>
    <img id="uploadedImage" src="" alt="Uploaded Image" style="display:none;">

    <script>
        document.getElementById('uploadButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
            const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            const file = fileInput.files[0];

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', file);

            const response = await fetch('/api/message', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });
            const result = await response.text();
            alert(result);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

サーバー（AzureFunctions）プログラム
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

app.http('message', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        let returnText = "";
        returnText = "test";
        upload.single('image')(request, null, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                returnText = "upload: error in upload.single";
            }
            if (!request.file) {
                returnText = "upload: No file uploaded";
                return;
            }
            context.log("upload: result:", request.file);
            returnText = "upload: Files uploaded successfully"
        });
        return { body: `return value =  ${returnText}` };
    },
});


input type="file" を以下のように form タグで囲ったらどうなりますか？
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</form>


【追記】
form タグで囲わないと multipart/form-data 形式にならないのではと思って上のレスをしましたが、質問者さんのコードではそういうことはなかったです。見当違いのレスですみません。
質問の「クライアントプログラム」とほぼ同じコードで期待通り multipart/form-data 形式でサーバーに送信されます。

自分の環境の ASP.NET Web アプリでは、上の画像のようにアップロードされたファイルは正しく取得できます。
ということで、サーバー側の問題だと思われますが、AzureFunctions というものには触ったこともないので何が問題なのか分かりません。
お役に立てずすみませんが、他の方の回答をお待ちください。
